# What should we put in non-programming-language tag documentations?

Tags: discussion, documentation

What programming languages should we use for tag documentations that are not about a certain programming language?

There exist some tags that are about general concepts in programming, something that is not local to just one or two programming languages. However, there are still tags created for them specifically, and there are also people who commit to create documentation for them.

According to the Documentation Tour:

> Documentation is divided up by its subject matter, the library, language, framework, etc. that developers are using.

Libraries. Languages. Frameworks. These are all OK ‐ they are all very specific. But tags such as math, arrays, loops, etc., are very broad.

I have been looking at the [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/algorithm) tag. So far it has been OK, because it is written using pseudocode. Regarding which style of pseudocode should be used, it is probably not a big thing, as discussed in [this thread about code style in documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328528/3990767).

But what about topics which are related to the syntax? For example, in this topic about [accessing arrays in the arrays documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/arrays/4260/various-ways-of-accessing-arrays#t=201608111501329593879), examples in C, Java and JavaScript have been discussed (seems like the guys contributing to that documentation really love JavaScript?).

Meanwhile, there is this extremely specific topic https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/arrays/2466/array-prototype-reduce#t=201608111512218727545 (this question does not discuss the scope of a topic (although it is almost common sense that one very specific function in a language isn't worth a topic), but I'm talking about whether it should exist in such a manner in the first place). Indeed, there exists a function related to reducing an array in many languages, and array reduction is probably really worth a topic in that section.

The problem is, do we really want to have an example for every language in documentations like this? In the first place, such documentation was probably created to introduce the concept of arrays, and then probably algorithms behind them as well. Maybe also these specific functions, but if we introduce them at a per-language scope, this obviously duplicates *every programming language*'s topic about arrays.

I'm not talking about the duplication of topics over different tags. This is probably not a problem here, since users can find them easily from both sources. The trouble is in the redundancy of creating an example per language. I don't have any citation behind this point, but by common sense, I believe that very few people (basically only people adding arrays to a new language) would want to see a comparison/summary of the syntax for arrays for each language. This is probably very redundant, especially when this is expected for every topic in the arrays documentation, which is probably going to be either unsystematic or time-consuming.

On the other hand, if we don't do it for every language, which language should we be using for each example? Pseudocode is probably not available in every case.

---

> Don't blame my excessive use of "probably". That's the key to get high scores in your essays.

Comment: *math, arrays, loops* should all be covered in the language docs.  I don't see why we need a generic Loops docs.

Comment: @NathanOliver Not mentioning how this is probably a solution to duplicating content in different language docs, a generic doc about loops can be about more details related to it, such as algorithms that are related to loops, but nothing specific to that language, and normally people won't put it into language docs (because language docs are about how you use it in that language, and these docs that I call "concept docs" can dig into more detail about their actual usage, which is what examples should have been for).

Answer (score 5):

> What programming languages should we use for tag documentations that are not about a certain programming language?

None, because there shouldn't be tags for Documentation about "general" concepts. Documentation is for supplementing and localizing documentation *of programming languages*.

This is my opinion.